# querySelector not getting element in lightning web component

Tags: javascript, html, lightning-web-components

I am creating a popover, where I need to position it correctly based on the button's position that triggered it.

It starts like this:

```
<div id="popoverWrapper" class="popover-wrapper" style={popoverStyle}>
    <section id="popover" class="slds-popover slds-popover_walkthrough slds-popover_large slds-nubbin_left" role="dialog">
        <!--all the insides of the popover-->
    </section
</div>
```

I initially just tried a getter on popoverStyle, but when trying to do `this.template.querySelector('.popover-wrapper');` it returned null. I thought maybe this was because the getter was happening before actual render.

So I moved the querySelector to the `renderedCallback()` hook. Putting in a break point, the html is definitely rendered by the time I get to `this.template.querySelector('.popover-wrapper');` but it still doesn't find anything.

How might I be able to grab the element in my LWC so I can get its position and dimensions to be able to position properly where I want by finding a space that it will fit?

PS: popoverStyle is getting set to a string that looks like: `position: absolute; z-index: 10001; top: ' + correctPositioning.offsetTop + 'px; left: ' + correctPositioning.offsetLeft + 'px;`. I am not entirely sure this will even work, but I can't even find the popover element in my JS to try it out.

Comment: i tried your code in renderedCallback and it worked. [Playgound link](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/XNTPMBRfr/2/edit)

Comment: Well, that makes it difficult lol. My component is on a Visualforce page, so I have a lightning component that creates an LWC table with buttons, and those buttons create the LWC popover that is having the issues. I wouldn't think it being nested like that would impact it, especially since I am doing `this.template`. But yeah, querySelector returned an empty object in my renderedCallback...

Comment: Are you sure there's no other errors loading your component? What does `this.template.querySelectorAll("*")` return in your components `renderedCallback`?

Comment: Can you try something similar - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/XNTPMBRfr/76/edit

Answer (score 1):

You probably have an error in your component related with the way that you are trying to set the styles, if you remove `style={popoverStyle}` the `this.template.querySelector('.popover-wrapper')` must return you the element and there you can set directly using JS, like:

```
let popup = this.template.querySelector('.popover-wrapper');
popup.style.position = 'absolute';
```

Comment: Hello @Pirata21, I tried your answer, it doesn't seem to work. I am trying to get the width value of an element in javascript.          let mapWidth = this.template.querySelector('.map-root');
          console.log(mapWidth.style.width);